# send_file just sends an empty file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendfile

Im looking for a way to download a xml file. I use:

```
file_path = 'folder/' + xml_name + '.xml'
send_file file_path, :type => "text/xml"
```

but this always downloads me an empty file. The file itself has 16 KB of data in it...

why is that?

Maechi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem saved, but I don't know why

```
File.open(file_path, 'r') do |f|
  send_data f.read, :type => "text/xml", :filename => "10.xml"
end
```

send_data is working... but send_file not!

Comment: didnt worked for me.. both have the same issue in prod.. i checked the config for prod and the is disabled x_sendfile_header

Answer (score 24):

probably you have to comment out

`config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"`

in production.rb

see http://vijaydev.wordpress.com/2010/12/15/rails-3-and-apache-x-sendfile/ for explanations

Comment: If you are using nginx, you should use: config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'

Comment: This answer works for me, but I assume that installing/enabling mod_xsendfile would be the preferred solution.

Comment: Link is no longer accessible to public.

Answer (score 6):

As Eugene says in his answer, in a production enviroment Rails will let Apache or nginx send the actual file for you with x-sendfile, if you don't use either of these as the infrastructure for rails you have to comment out the line suggested in the

> config/environments/production.rb file.

```
# config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

Comment: +1 for actually explaining why to remove this header. On Heroku I'm using Unicorn.

Answer (score 3):

You must enable sendfile usage in `./config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile"
```

If this line is not present (or commented out), then Rails will correctly send the file, but not through Apache.

If you are getting 0-byte files, then make sure that you have installed `mod_xsendfile`, which is available from https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile

Download the single source file (`mod_xsendfile.c`) and compile it (`apxs -cia mod_xsendfile.c`).  You probably want to run `apxs` as root so that it will set up everything correctly.

Then you're going to want to set the `XSendFile` and `XSendFilePath` options in your Apache configuration files.   See the help at the above URL for more information.

Answer (score 1):

In my case same thing happened.
I was sending file and deleting it.
as here

```
File.open(file_path, 'r') do |f|      
  send_data f.read, filename: 'my_file.docx' , type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document', disposition: 'attachment'
end
File.delete(file)
```

but

```
filename: 'my_file.docx'
```

save my day