# Same Rails 4 routes for GET and POST requests

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, ruby-on-rails-4

In Rails 3 Match used to point to an action for both **"GET"** and **"POST"** and other type of requests.

```
match "user/account" => user#account
```

Now this will point to account action of user's controller for both GET and POST requests.
As in **Rails 4** "match" has been deprecated, can we create same route for **GET** and **POST** in Rails 4?

Comment: match won't just match GET and POST... it will match PUT, PATCH and DELETE as well.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

[From the `match` documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.0/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-match), you can use `match` as long as you have `via`:

```
match "user/account" => "user#account", as: :user_account, via: [:get, :post]
```

Edit: Added a `as:` parameter so that it will be accessible via a url helper. `user_account_path` or `user_account_url` in this case.

Comment: We also need to put " :as => action_name " with route to work with all cases.

Answer (score 46):

On routes, the match method will no longer act as a catch-all option. You should now specify which HTTP verb to respond to with the option :via

## Rails 3.2

```
match "/users/:id" => "users#show"
```

## Rails 4.0

```
match "/users/:id" => "users#show", via: :get
```

## or specify multiple verbs

```
match "/users" => "users#index", via: [:get, :post]
```

Another option for better Rails 3.2 compatibility is to just specify your actions with explicit get, post, or any other HTTP verb. With this option, you still get your code running today and future proof it for the upgrade.

## Rails 3.2 and 4.0 compatible

```
get "/users/:id" => "users#show"
```

## multiple verbs

```
get "/users" => "users#index"
post "/users" => "users#index"
```

Comment: Great answer, here more information about Rails 4 upgrade: http://www.sitepoint.com/get-your-app-ready-for-rails-4/

Comment: Sometimes, I see `to:` and sometimes just `=>`. Which one should I use for Rails 4?